# How to get next id in GRAILS?

Tags: oracle, grails, plsql, grails-orm

I need to get the next available id in a sequence, using GORM or native query.
How can I do this?

I'm using oracle.

---

**UPDATE:**

I need this value **BEFORE** insert, because my row will use this value.
I have table called IMAGE, with column FILE_NAME, like this:

```
- ID | FILE_NAME
- 123 | foo_bar_123.png
- 124 | xxx_yyy_124.png
```

Tks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need the value before the insert?  Could you get the information as part of the insert using the `RETURNING` clause, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table_name( id, file_name )
  VALUES( some_sequence.nextval, <<bind variable>> )
  RETURNING id INTO <<bind variable>>
```

Or access it after the insert using

```
SELECT sequence_name.currval
  FROM dual
```

The `currval` of a sequence returns the most recent value of the sequence produced in the current session so it is actually thread-safe.  Since sequences are designed to provide numbers in a highly concurrent environment, you cannot in general find out what the `nextval` is going to be unless you actually fetch the `nextval`.  Even if you could, there is no guarantee that another thread won't come along and get the value you peeked at before your `INSERT` took place so it wouldn't be safe to peek at the `nextval` in a multi-user environment.

Comment: I've tried nextval. Grails uses nextval too, so I'm afraid to get always id + 2, not id + 1. Example: 1, 3, 5, 7...but I want: 1, 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 1):

I adapted @Cave tips.
So, my solution is:

Change my mapping from:

```
class Image {
...
id column: "ID", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence:"MY_SEQUENCE"]
...
}
```

to:

```
class Image {
...
id column: "ID", generator: "assigned"
...
}
```

And set id mannualy using this:

```
def getLastImageId(){
  def sql = "SELECT MY_SEQUENCE.nextval FROM dual"
  def query = sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery(sql);
  def result = query.list()
  return result[0]
}
...
newImage.id = getLastImageId()
newImage.fileName = "foo_bar_${newImage.id}.png"
```